# flag reason for challenges or homework etc

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, close-reasons

What should I use as flag reasons for questions that are just trying to get someone else solve their tasks/homework/challenge? If I flag as off-topic, there are several reasons, but none of them seem to fit. For example, it isn't *blantly off-topic*, as it has something to do with programming, nor does it fit on other sites of the network, nor is it requesting debugging. 
Did I overlook something here? If no, as these type of question are not rare, I'm wondering why it isn't a off-topic close reason of its own.
Or should I just flag them as *unclear what you're asking*, or *very low quality*.

I mean the questions like: *"How can i do xy?"*, with no own effort, or just copy-pasting the task.

Comment: 'How can i do xy?, with no own effort, or just copy-pasting the task' - rude and abusive, but flagging as such is likely to be rejected:(

Comment: @MartinJames:  There's nothing rude about posting an assignment dump. It's a jerk move IRL, but otherwise too broad of a question here.

Comment: @Makoto there is.  It's inherently insulting to ask someone to do all their work for them for no wages.

Comment: Being insulted on an otherwise unobjectionable post is not cause to flag.  There's a valid flag to use; it should be used.

Answer (score 7):

## Homework questions are *not* implicitly off-topic.

I don't think this can be overstated.  A homework question is *fine* here as long as it fits within the scope of the site - that is, the question is complete, concise, clear and reasonably answerable.

The same goes for "challenge" questions - if they're on-topic, then no close reason applies for them.

As for the questions with no effort implied - a downvote and a flag as "Too Broad" is probably enough, although the downvote would be better in the long run.

Comment: Dang, that makes the second time today that you've beaten me to an answer by mere seconds.

Comment: Why do you think a downvote is better in the long run?

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser:  More immediate and visible feedback on the quality of the question, really.

Comment: @Makoto Do these kind of questions stay normally unanswered? (I'm asking, because I'm more familiar with SE-sites with lower question rates) If they do, what you say makes sense, of course.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser: I don't see why they wouldn't be answered? I answer homework questions from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

For a question like what you describe, **don't flag it, just downvote and move on.**

Homework questions *can* be on-topic. They frequently aren't, but there is nothing *inherently* wrong about asking for help with your homework.